# Al usar Clases Abstractas en Java obtengo actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, poo, clase-abstracta

Estoy aprendiendo POO en Java, específicamente parte de lo que son Clases y Métodos abstractos. El caso es que estoy creando la clase abstracta Jugador, de donde voy a crear la subclase Mago:

```
public abstract class Jugador{
    private String nombre;
    private int vida;
    private int xp;
    private int fuerza;
    private int inteligencia;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public abstract int ataque();
    public abstract int hechizo();
    ...
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

```
public class Mago extends Jugador{

    public Mago(String nombre, int vida, int xp, int fuerza, int intelignecia, ...){
        super(vida,xp,fuerza,inteligencia,energia,mana); //AQUI ME ARROJA ERROR
    }

    @Override
    public int ataque(){
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public int hechizo(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Cuando quiero heredar los atributos de Jugador para Mago (la línea del super(), asumiendo que energia y mana también están definidos en Jugador) me dice lo siguiente:

*constructor Jugador in class Jugador cannot be applied to given types*

*required: no arguments*

*found: int,int,int,int,int,int*

*reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

Tal vez sea un error algo absurdo, pero la verdad no logro ver que es lo que me falta (o me sobra), si alguien me podría orientar estaré muy agradecido, por favor.

Comment: Es porque `Jugador` no tiene un constructor que reciba esos parámetros.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java: actual and formal argument lists differ in length](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575790/java-actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ-in-length)

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir el constructor en la clase padre que acepta esos parámetros,  el constructor por default, que esta implicito, no lleva parámetros .

```
public abstract class Jugador{
    private String nombre;
    private int vida;
    private int xp;
    ...

    public Jugador(int vida,int xp,int fuerza,int inteligencia,int energia, int mana){
        ...
    }

}
```