# Java: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, poo, objeto, class

Tengo este código:

```java
public class TimeInstant {
    // ATRIBUTOS:
    /** 
     *  Variable entera para almacenar las horas. 
     *  Debe pertenecer al rango [0..23].
     */
   private int hours;
    /** 
     *  Variable entera para almacenar los minutos. 
     *  Debe pertenecer al rango [0..59]. 
     */
   private int minutes;   
    
    // CONSTRUCTORES:
    /**
     *  Crea un TimeInstant con el valor de las horas y 
     *  los minutos que recibe como argumentos,iniHours
     *  y iniMinutes, respectivamente.
     *  Precondición: 0 <= iniHours < 24, 0 <= iniMinutes < 60.
     */
   public void TimeInstant (int _h, int _m){
        if((_h >= 0 && _h < 24) && (_m >= 0 && _m < 60)){
            this.hours = _h; this.minutes = _m;
        }else{
            System.err.println("Los datos introducidos son incorrectos. <hours>: Range[0;23]; <minutes>: Range[0;59];");
        }
    }
        
    /**
     * Crea un TimeInstant con el valor del instante
     * actual UTC (tiempo universal coordinado).
     */
    public void TimeInstant(){
        long tMinTotal = System.currentTimeMillis() / (60 * 1000);
        int tMinCurrent = (int)(tMinTotal % (24 * 60));
        
        this.hours = tMinCurrent / 60;
        this.minutes = tMinCurrent % 60;
    }

// ...

}
```

Pero cuando intento invocar la clase

```java
TimeInstant  t = new TimeInstant(2, 12);
```

Me devuelve este error:

```bash
Error: constructor TimeInstant in class time.TimeInstant cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los constructores en Java no declaran ningún tipo, Si tienes una clase A, se asume que su constructor es un método que devuelve una instancia de A. Por tanto se omite el tipo en el método e incluso se omite el return:

```java
    public TimeInstant (int _h, int _m){
        if ( _h >= 0 && _h < 24 && _m >= 0 && _m < 60) {
            this.hours = _h;
            this.minutes = _m;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Los datos introducidos son incorrectos. <hours>: Range[0;23]; <minutes>: Range[0;59];");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya me va. Esto es lo que he modificado [Código](https://zhenglinlei.github.io/paste-code/#XQAAAQBAAgAAAAAAAAAtiIH4IBEs3CPxXIb+Uuz9nBzCVY1U7PGDTp2t30BnhrKcMtQQX2yZCtIIIS0Z6bo3Dm10QATIxuNIpvodD+M/HfKx9bRNTd6rlV4NataWFL4NKmrA16fBNXVuNg0wIllQi3ZCfOy0I7X/MuAimSIseTDR2LGvk9+Tt57fFmkk2vs4u7KmxcFnc2gQPbL6MbPOtYFLZHsXZggvCUKqIgcJzN5XgP5kZXgo7Mxyg3e1h8whSwaT4r5VOzhVsk8hk/y8yfFL4rgSFKL5H5FPrWmf5gyDiYl02VA6Fa76lmzXR4U++vxWFHPSHuJCfWiatipJ67qbNAiJMji8xaBIX9JcSJgPYDJsQNxOlzSUanqjop0EU5OQPA/CK1bjE7I8Bm6op0JEnzxzT9b7PRn6f/+gtQwA)